# showing ImportError: cannot import name 'Template' while Using from PIL import Image

Tags: python-3.5, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on Image recognition program
Using:
python 3.5
PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3 as IDE
and i installed the Pillow 3.1.2 using *pip install Pillow*

my code is:

```python
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('images/dot.png')
im.load()
```

while RUN it shows the error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harry/PycharmProjects/python study/image.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 31, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harry/PycharmProjects/python study/image.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 31, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
*
```

Please can anyone help with this issue

Answer (score 14):

There is a file named "string.py" in your current working directory.
You should not named the file as same as the modules in Python Standard Library or reserved word.

Change the name of file "string.py" to something else, then it will work

[image]